# Is it possible to kill a "android:persistent=true" system-level app?

Tags: android

I have an app that is just a service that launches on boot. I am developing at the system level, so I am using `android:persistent=true` in order to ensure my service is not killed under memory pressure.

However, I find this prevents me from killing my service under *any* conditions. I still want to be able to kill it myself - is there a way to do this, or is it impossible because "persistent=true" is defined in the manifest?

If this is not possible, how else can I protect my process from dying under memory pressure? Can I define a priority by hand? Perhaps `oom_score` or something?

Comment: Does killBackgroundProcesses(packageName) work?

Comment: Calling `stopSelf()` stops the service. Or do you really need to _kill_ it?

Comment: @Ozbek - I need to kill process to save the precious 1mb memory.

Comment: @Memme killBackgroundProcess does't work but your comment lead me to forceStopPackage, which is a hidden ActivityManager function for system apps. I think this may work, but I am testing

Comment: @EricS. My question is why do you need to kill the service? Why not simply stop it?

Comment: @Ozbek - What's the difference between killing a service and stopping a service? Are you defining "stop" as requesting a stop and "kill" as force killing the process? If so, the only reason is that stopping a service doesn't work with a persistent process - it just gets restarted.

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out. Most methods of stopping the service will not stop the persistent flag from restarting it. This includes stopService, killBackgroundService, and even System.exit(0);

There is a hidden function called `forceStopPackage` in ActivityManagerService that you can invoke through the ActivityManager interface by reflection. Requires system privileges, but that shouldn't be an issue if you are using persistent.

In Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"></uses-permission>
```

This will kill the process. Give it name of process/package.

```
try {
        Class c;
        c = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManager");
        Method m = c.getMethod("forceStopPackage", new Class[]{String.class});
        Object o = m.invoke(null, new Object[]{"com.your.process"});
    }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to kill service", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:persistent=true
```

Works for preloaded applications, doesn't work for downloaded applications (e.g. APPs from Play Store, installed from apk or AS)
Suggest to use foreground service method - The highest priority process.
[Official example here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground), [Another full-code example here](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/09/simple-android-foreground-service-example/)